# Light persistent local queue or database for scheduled thread pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, threadpool

I have a REST API provided by Spring boot app. Everything is working fine.

Now,
some kind of request can force a long computation, however I must return response immediately. I am going to push the request to queue (fast and light and persistent) and configure ScheduledThreadPool (Java 8)

In this aim I am using Java 8 Thread Pool.

However, I can't find such queue (it may be also some local database).
And generally - what do you think about this approach ?

Comment: I'd use an out-of-process queue, such as RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ, which provides the speed and persistence you want, as well as the ability to read/write from multiple servers.

Comment: To my eye, RabbitMQ is overkill here